# Aurelia - Accessing ViewModel functions/binding from within Generated DOM elements

Tags: dom, aurelia

I have a section of my view (html) that is generated programmatically by a viewmodel/class. This uses the Aurelia `DOM` ([Aurelia Docs - pal :: Dom](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/pal/1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/doc/api/interface/Dom)) functionality to generate and add the raw HTML elements to the view.

However, I am unable to get events within the generated html to call back to the viewmodel. An example:

```
let deleteButton = this.dom.createElement("button");
deleteButton.setAttribute("onclick", "cancelCreditNote(`${ row.creditNoteId }`)");
```

A click on the generated button won't call back to the viewmodel, which does have a `cancelCreditNote` function. Various other things like `deleteButton.setAttribute("click.delegate", "cancelCreditNote('${ row.creditNoteId }')");` do not work either.

**Does anyone know how to access a viewmodel class from essentiall 'raw' html in aurelia?**

Unfortunately in this instance I cannot use the standard aurelia templating to generate the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM property on PAL is just an abstraction for the browser's DOM object, create element is likely just calling `document.createElement` which doesn't afford any Aurelia binding to the created element.

You could try using `aurelia.enhance(context, element)` which takes an existing DOM element and runs it through the templating engine.

With this method you can also pass a binding context to apply to the element.

Answer (score 0):

In my HTML I use this:

```
<div id="collapsesidebar" click.delegate="toggleSidebar()">
```

In my view-model I have this method:

```
toggleSidebar(){
    alert('hi');
}
```

You could also do this from your view-model with JQuery like this:

```
attached() {
    $('main').on('click', ()=> alert('hi'));
}
```

The last option is ONLY available áfter the `attached()` method is triggered: before that the binding needs to do its job and only after that the elements are located inside of the dom.

In other words: this **will not work:**

```
activate(){
    $('main').on('click', ()=> alert('hi'));
}
```

because the `constructor` and the `activate` method both get fired **before** the `attached` method.

Comment: I'll try adding behavior to the elements in the attached method and will report back.